# Manga with time travel or reincarnation; a guy went back in time and has an evil spirit girl inside

Tags: story-identification, manga

Please help me find this manga, the main character is a guy who went back in time and has some black haired evil spirit girl inside him. His friend died in the first life, now they are friends again and he has an elven girl spirit with a wind power. Probably fantasy/post-apocalyptic setting with knights and magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It might be Korean or Chinese origin, I really don't remember, it was last year, but no idea about how old it was. The computer on which I've read it is gone.

Comment: How did the friend die? Also, why did the main character go back time? It's a common trope for a main character to go back in time after they die, but you didn't indicate that the main character died in this story; only the friend.

Comment: The friend was killed by something, long ago. He was from some elite group...from some experiments on kids I think. The MC was glad he found him again. Yeah I think he went back because everyone died, MC as the last one.

Answer (score 1):

**

### Ordinary Soldier Dreams of the Past Alt title: Hiraheishi wa Kako wo Yumemiru

**

After a long battle, John Celias, a soldier of the Demon punitive force, sees the hero topple the Demon King at last...and he is defeated by the remnants of the enemy. When John, who should have died in the war, wakes up, he finds that he has become a baby in his hometown... the same hometown that should have been destroyed by the demons. John realizes that he has actually gone back in time and decides to use the fighting prowess and the knowledge he gained in his previous life to change his tragic fate! It's a story of a soldier and his time travel counterattack fantasy!
[image]